# Multiple words search across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, search, full-text-search

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "firstName" varchar NOT NULL,
    "middleName" varchar NULL,
    "lastName" varchar NOT NULL
);
```

How to construct a query to search across all fields with partial support?

Assuming I have the following entries:

```
firstName middleName lastName
John      Mark       Smith
Barbara   Alice      Johnson
John      Bob        Johson
```

When I search for:

'joh smi' or 'smi joh' I would like to retrieve the first record

but when I search for 'joh joh' I would only like to retrieve the last record but not the first two.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use two words to search (one name and one last name but you don't know which is which), you can create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION twoWordsSearchForContacts(words text) RETURNS SETOF contact AS
$$

DECLARE

aWords text[] := string_to_array(words, ' ');

word1 text := aWords[1];
word2 text := aWords[2];

BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY SELECT * 
               FROM contact 
               WHERE ("lastName" ILIKE '%' || word1 || '%' AND "firstName" || ' ' || "middleName" ILIKE '%' || word2 || '%')
                       OR ("lastName" ILIKE '%' || word2 || '%' AND "firstName" || ' ' || "middleName" ILIKE '%' || word1 || '%');
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Using the function:

```
SELECT * FROM twoWordsSearchForContacts('smi joh');
```

You can also split words directly in the query without using a function.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually came up with something very similar but not using an SQL function but a function in typescript (in my ORM service). I am wondering though if it would be possible to come up with a more generic solution that would make it possible to search using an arbitrarty number of fields and words

Comment: You are welcome @Funkycoder!!! Yes, It is possible, but you have to define how to search using them (for example: each word have to be present in all columns or just in one of them, etc).